# Problem with v6 subnet routing

Tags: routing, ipv6, subnet

I have a freebsd machine connecting to my sixxs ayiya-tunnel.
As I decided to implement IPv6 in our complete network and not only one interface I got myself a routed /48 from sixxs.
I'll use 2001:DB8::/32 as of RFC3849 to describe my setup.
My subnet therefore is 2001:DB8:ae02::/48.

I've added a /64 to each vlan:
vlan200: 2001:DB8:ae02:ca75::1/64
vlan210: 2001:DB8:ae02:beef::1/64
and so on.

I can ping every IP I configure from any external host and the traffic shows up on my tun0 interface but doesn't get routed to the vlan-interface.
I therefore assume I am missing a route for my /48 somewhere.
When issueing a ping6 -I vlan210 google.com I get a `no route to host` error.

Amongs many link local routes this seems to be the relevant part of my routing table (everything mentioning my subnet + the default route):

```
default                           2001:db8:ff00:1a92::1        UGS        tun0  
::1                               link#4                        UH          lo0  
::ffff:0.0.0.0/96                 ::1                           UGRS        lo0  
2001:db8:ae02:beef::             2001:db8:ae02:beef::1        UH2        vlan210 =>  
2001:db8:ae02:beef::/64          link#7                        U       vlan210  
2001:db8:ae02:beef::1            link#7                        UHS         lo0  
2001:db8:ae02:ca75::             2001:db8:ae02:ca75::1        UH2     vlan200 =>  
2001:db8:ae02:ca75::/64          link#6                        U       vlan200  
2001:db8:ae02:ca75::1            link#6                        UHS         lo0
```